# Мне надо создать массив по значению переменной

Tags: php

Вот что у меня получилось

```
$array = '"1", "2", "3", "4"';
$array_array = array($array);
print_r($array_array);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если  в результате вы ожидаете массив с элементами 1,2,3 и 4 то

```
$result = explode(',', $array);
```

иначе не понятно о чем вы

Comment: Я массив создал. Но теперь в этом массиве через in_array нельзя получить ответ.

Comment: @AimBot в смысле? `in_array(1, $result)` должно вернуть `true`

Comment: Да.
if (in_array(1, $result))
{
    echo "123";
}

Comment: @AimBot и чего? не выводит что ли?

Comment: У меня не выводит

Comment: Остались кавычки

Comment: @AimBot ну ничего удивительного, у вас элементы `"1"` и т.п. с кавычками

Comment: Да
Но я их убрал и тоже самое

Comment: @splash58 опередил на пару секунд :)

Comment: Всё заработало, спасибо

Comment: @reran Ну, уж, извини ))